# How to pass json data to ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me with this issue. I use jquery UI autocomplete plugin. Is there a way to pass json data like this

> [{'username' : 'user1}, {'username' :
>   'user2}, {'username' : 'user3}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create an array of usernames. With jQuery, you could do the following:

```
var jsonData = [{'username' : 'user1'}, {'username' : 'user2'}, {'username' : 'user3'}];
var usernames = $.map(jsonData, function (obj) { return obj.username; });

$("#myInput").autocomplete({source: usernames});
```

Comment: Variable jsonData have json data
console.log(usernames) return [] - no data

Comment: @Matt: `$.map` does not return a jQuery object, just an array; no need to call `.get()`.

Comment: @Peter: running the first two lines of my code in the console works; the problem must be elsewhere in your code, e.g. in the format of your JSON. Is it a string, maybe? In that case use `JSON.parse` to turn it into an actual JavaScript object.

Comment: Now works. I forgot to parse incoming data with $.parseJSON
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surely the documentation for the plugin must state something about this, however your question is vague at best. Which plugin are you using? Does it have any service methods to put data into?

Comment: This belongs as a comment, not an answer. I am aware that you do not yet have enough rep to comment on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `source` option in the [Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source). It can be a local JavaScript array.

Comment: Please understand the terminology so you don't misuse it. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Fair. However, the JSON needs to be an array of values in order for the autocompleter to work. Albeit unclear, it is not a misuse.